# How to loop through xml nodes in Oracle Service Bus console - Xquery?

Tags: xquery, esb, osb, alsb

I have created a `Proxy Service` in pipeline I wanted to transform the incoming xml to some other structure. Like

```
<body>
  <prices>
      <price>$100</price>
  </prices>
  <prices>
      <price>E100</price>
  </prices>
</body>
```

Should be transformed to

```
<body>
  <prices>
      <price>$100</price>
      <type>USD</type>
  </prices>
  <prices>
      <price>E100</price>
      <type>UERO</type>
  </prices>
</body>
```

From the pipline stage I have selected `Add Action -> Flow Control -> For Each`

And I have selected `body/prices/*` in the Xquery builder.

Butt none of the `prices` tag are processed.

I get "with total count in variable " `totalCount` is zero always.

Answer (score 0):

select body/prices/price instead of body/prices/*